# ANGULAR - How the EventEmitter Service below, works exactly?

Tags: javascript, angular

On my work, we've been using this **service** below to subscribe and emit notifications right and fourth. As a junior developer I already understand Input and Outputs of Angular and sort of how Emitters work.

But this service simplys confuse me. The dev who made this service already left the company and since this code is almost a boilerplate for all projects, I cannot ask him how exactly it works.

specifically this line: **private static emitters: { [notificationName: string]: EventEmitter } = {}**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EventEmitterService {

    private static emitters: { [notificationName: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {}

    static get(notificationName: string): EventEmitter<any> {
        if (!this.emitters[notificationName])
            this.emitters[notificationName] = new EventEmitter<any>();
        return this.emitters[notificationName];
    }
}

/** 
to SUBSCRIBE:

private subscriptions = new Subscription();   
constructor(){
    this.subscriptions.add( EventEmitterService.get("notification_name").subscribe(payload => this.notificationHandler(payload)) );
}

TO EMIT: 

EventEmitterService.get("notificationName").emit(payload); 

to UNSUBSCRIBE:

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
*/
```

Following instructions from the user Michael D, I've change the code

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

private emitters: { [notificationName: string]: Subject<any> } = { };
```

and got this error:

[image: Error]

The error was caused because the return of `static get(notificationName: string):` was not changed to `Observable<any>`

So the final form of service, updated according to MichaelD comment :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EventEmitterService {

    // private static emitters: { [notificationName: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {}
    private  emitters: { [notificationName: string]: Subject<any> } = {};


    get(notificationName: string): Observable<any>{
        if (!this.emitters[notificationName])
            this.emitters[notificationName] = new EventEmitter<any>();
        return this.emitters[notificationName];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is like any other service where type of `emitters ` is `EventEmitter `. What's confusing? On the other note, why does it feel like I wrote this code 3 years ago :D

Comment: How it works.
`private static emitters: { [notificationName: string]: EventEmitter<any> } = {}`
Whats is this: `emitters` is object type? ok I guess. But whats about this `[notificationName: string]`? Is inside square brackets... :?

Comment: It just means that the type is an object where the key is a string (notificationName is an alias) and the value is an EventEmitter instance, check out Typescript's documentation on it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been seeing this pattern of using [`EventEmitters`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in services frequently. `EventEmitters` are **NOT** meant to used in services. It is used to emit custom events from components to it's parent components.

The [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts) is an interface extension of RxJS [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject). If a multicast observable is required in the service, then the RxJS `Subject` (or `BehaviorSubject`) could be used.

In your case, the `emitter` variable is an object with a property `notificationName` that will point to the emitter.

Also I do not understand the meaning of `static` here. The service is already made a singleton with the `{ providedIn: 'root' }` argument. There isn't going to be multiple instances of the `emitters`.

You could also have the same behavior with the following

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

private emitters: { [notificationName: string]: Subject<any> } = { };
```

Comment: I edited the question with a print and the new code. But got an error :/

Comment: The return type of getter should be changed to `Observable` as well. Try: `static get(notificationName: string): Observable<any>`

Comment: It worked, but the use, will be exactly the same. No need for reworks besides the instantiation of EventEmitterService on classes constructors?
I'm assuming this is more "angular" way than the other?

Comment: The basic functionality would be the same. It is the more *Angulary* way of doing things. However you need to adapt the entire service according to it. For eg. the aforementioned return type issue. You need to adjust all the types in the service accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Event Emitter model basically follows the observable pattern. In above code I we created a static emitter means we can call it without an instance of class. So this will five us a behavior like utility. You need to understand only one thing. Emitters are constantly listening to the Events and as the event happens they emit the response regardless of success or failure. This response is pretty similar to the interrupt generated by hardware in our OS which make the CPU to listen that specific interrupt instead of doing other tasks. So when we have an update in out Event EventEmitter will broadcast that change and our listeners will detect it on that specific Event

Answer (score 1):

```js
private static emitters: { [notificationName: string]: EventEmitter } = {}
```

This line just means that `emitters` is an internal property of the `EventEmitterService` class of type object, for which keys are strings, and values instances of `EventEmitter`. It's being used to keep track of active subscriptions.
The consumers of the service are not concerned with other consumers, they just want to `emit` or `subscribe` to a given notification, that's why it's private.

If you look at the [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) interface, you'll see that you can indeed either `emit` or `subscribe`. When you emit you send a payload that will be passed as a parameter to the function consumers subscribed with.

When you `subscribe` to an `EventEmitter`, it returns a subscription which you can then `unsubscribe` from.
When you add your `EventEmitter` subscription to `subscriptions`, you're allowing yourself to be able to unsubscribe to all of them at once by calling its `unsubscribe`.